# how to insert html tags into base template? (Django Python )

Tags: python, django

I want to dynamically generate a page using the base template

I need to insert a piece of HTML code on the page

I have checkboxes and after selecting some, generate new ones according to favorites.

It doesn't work as it should :

```
def index(request):
    context = {'content': '<h1>hello</h1>'}
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

on the HTML page :

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```

how to insert html tags into base template?

Comment: before you return as HttpResponse you need to render the content in order to convert django tags into html

Comment: its not possible what you're doing.

Comment: @Razenstein
 how can i do that?

Comment: see the answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tags you want to use are django specific tags that neet to be converted by the django renderer. Put the html in a template file and render it as response:

```
def index(request):

   ....

 return render(request, "path/your_template.html", context)
```

please follow the django docs to understand where to place the templates so that django will find them.

Comment: I caught Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
context must be a dict rather than set.

Comment: `
def index(request):
    context= {'content': '<h1>hello</h1>'}
    return render(request, 'base.html', context) `

and have <h1>hello</h1>... have any ideas how to transfer HTML?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `render`:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
context = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return render(request,'yourapp_name/your_html.html',context)
```

**your_html.html**

```
{% extends 'yourapp_name/base.html' %} 

{% block content %}

Hello

{% endblock %}
```

remember your html files should have this path: `yourapp_name/templates/yourapp_name/your_html.html`

Comment: I can't insert the generated content

Comment: @VG would you please be more specific ?

Comment: I have checkboxes and after selecting some, generate new ones according to favorites. Displaying the whole page in a string is awful, I'm looking for an easier option

Comment: If I may suggest: please follow one of the django basic tutorials in order to get familiar with the philosophy and frist steps. It seems you are new to html, javascript etc. also.